# HttpContext is null after adding MessageHandler

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, controller, httpcontext

I am developing a WebAPI and have been receiving my POST data like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public Int16 Foo()
        {
            var input = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            Model_Deserialized model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model_Deserialized>(input);
            ...
        }
```

Recently I felt the need to log all the requests there were being sent over. I am trying to use the method suggested at http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi but after following those steps, my input variable started being an empty string.

This is how my Message Handler looks like

```
public abstract class MessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var corrId = string.Format("{0}{1}", DateTime.Now.Ticks, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var requestInfo = string.Format("{0} {1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);

            var requestMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            String ip;

            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
            {
                var ctx = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
                if (ctx != null)
                {
                    ip = ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                 ip = "error";
            }

            await IncommingMessageAsync(corrId, requestInfo, requestMessage, ip);

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            return response;
        }


        protected abstract Task IncommingMessageAsync(string correlationId, string requestInfo, byte[] message, String ip);
    }
```

and this is my MessageLoggingHandler

```
public class MessageLoggingHandler : MessageHandler
    {
        protected override async Task IncommingMessageAsync(string correlationId, string requestInfo, byte[] message, String ip)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
                WriteToFile(ip + "{" + correlationId + "} - Request: {" + requestInfo + "}\r\n{" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message) + "}"));
        }


        private void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            string path = "C:\\Logs\\ServiceLog" + DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + ".txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "--" + text);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added this to my Global.asax

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageLoggingHandler());
```

In my web.config I already tried adding

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Is there anyway to stick to this method instead of creating a logging routine and call it from every function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear `HttpContext` cannot be null - it is static. So is `HttpContext.Current` null? OR my guess is that `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream` is null. Web api automatically reads the stream and disposes it and deserializes the post body to your action input. So you should code your Web Api action to something like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public Int16 Foo(Model_Deserialized model)
{

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just to add - Web Api abstracts away most cases of serialization/de-serialization so in most cases you should not be doing manual de-serialization.

Comment: This WebAPI is for a mobile app. I used to serialize the data in the app and deserialize in the api, should I just send the data as a model?

Comment: Also...does this mean that if my MessageHandler reads the InputStream before my controller, it just disposes the content? Does the method of direct deserialization will solve this issue?

Comment: Using the information that the InputStream can only be read once, I changed my controller to

     HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

And got it to work